# Why the "Extra" Diode in this DC Motor Driver?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, diodes, motor

I've been shown this circuit, which uses a MOSFET to allow a 5V signal (from an Arduino Uno) to drive a 5V DC motor.  I know that diode D1 is a flyback diode to protect the motor when it turns off, but what is the function of diode D2?

EDIT:  I misspoke; D1 protects the MOSFET, not the motor.  Whoops!

[image: Motor driver circuit, showing a diode "D1" connected between the terminals of the motor to dissipate current when the motor is turned off, and another diode "D2" connected between the motor and the MOSFET.]

Comment: D2 is unnecessary. The person probably doesn't know what they are doing unless it is to prevent reverse polarity.

Comment: Oh, I bet that's it!  In this circuit, I bet the diode is to prevent damage to the circuit if the power (5V and Ground) is applied in reverse polarity.

Comment: If D2 intentionally there and the motor really is a 5 volt motor, the supply to the + terminal of the motor should be more like 5.6-5.8 volts depending on its current demand.  Also NTE2984 is rated at 12 A (100C). If this is a hefty motor, D2 will have to be rated high as well.  So for me several things don't make sense here.

Comment: D1 is a flyback diode but it is not to protect the motor, that is what is creating the flyback pulse. It is there to protect the MOSFET however many MOSFETs do not need a flyback diode if they have an appropriate UIS (avalanche) rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inductance of the motor will ring with the output capacitance of the FET. The Schottky diode in series with Q1 will reduce noise.

Motor control circuits are notoriously noisy. If noise is not a problem, the series diode may be removed. Modern standards for radiated and conducted noise are much more stringent that was the case many years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Without D2 there is a chance that motor will give a noise spike that will force current to through mosfet's diode. This diode could be quite weak and could increase heating on the whole mosfet or burn it, with a small chance. I dont think D2 is actually needed unless it is a critical application.

upd: when DC motor switches polarity internally, using mechanical collector or semiconductor switches, for a short time it works as a generator, providing power to the circuit. Depending on switching time it can provide impulse of either polarity. One polarity spike can be dissipated by the freewheeling diode D1. Reverse polarity spike can force mosfet's diode to conduct, if D2 is not present. Usually mosfet's diode is somewhat weaker than the mosfet itself, so if mosfet is close to its limit, there is some chance of damage to the mosfet's structure. Or just a bit more heating. Added diode D2 can hold this spike as a voltage rise around itself.

Comment: I have never heard of this or the physics for it, so either you are wrong or you are right but few people know so need to elaborate.

Comment: @DKNguyen Lets consider 4 cases: Mosfet blocks current, motor has current down - D1 saves the mosfet. Mosfet blocks the current, motor has current up - mosfet cant remain closed, its diode starts to conduct OR diode D2 blocks this spike charging its own capacity. Mosfet conducts, motor has current up - motor charges the battery without affecting mosfet's diode. Mosfet conducts, motor has current down - battery increases current in motor. DC motor as shown, likely has collector or switching transistors, both can make spikes of current in either direction as they switch.

Comment: Okay, so you are referring to cases where the motor might acting as a generator and the MOSFET opens to interrupt the generator current.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes. DC motor acts as a generator during the internal polarity switch. Both, in collector and switching transistor cases. It is not much, but i guess author was overly cautious. Or it was a critical application. Thats what I think anyway. Could be something else.

Comment: You should edit that into your post since kick from motor generating is typically not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Overall circuit / Arduino / connection reversal protection but only if the MOSFET breaks down. I don't normally put diodes in when driving a motor using a microcontroller. I'd ditch both.

There's an interesting video on back EMF which may highlight why diodes are used.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hReCPMIcLHg

Comment: Omitting both diodes sounds like very poor advice, Mark. You might get away with it on a one-off amateur project where financial loss caused by circuit failure might be low but omitting D1 certainly would not be recommended for a commercial product.

Comment: The video you linked to explains why not putting a diode across the motor is a bad idea. And there is another reason - if you are controlling motor speed with PWM the diode improves efficiency by recirculating back-emf current through the motor.